# How to put certain Data on Column in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Im Very New in java and im still learning how to put data on notepad. but i want to put one text to the JTable. [I Dont know how to put those arrowed text into JTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2HV3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a TableModel then add rows of data to your table model. There is plenty of information here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html